# How to unify numbers in a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I have a table with data:

```
000001
123
00123
123456
1234
mydog
04456mydog
```

And I want all numbers `<10000` formatted as four digits like so:

```
0001
0123
0123
123456
1234
mydog
04456mydog
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
UPDATE test
   SET digits = LPAD(CAST(digits AS UNSIGNED), 4, '0')
 WHERE digits REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
   AND CAST(digits AS UNSIGNED) < 10000;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78832/1).

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it. This could work:

```
select case when YourField REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$' and cast(YourField as unsigned) < 10000 then LPAD(RIGHT(YourField, 4), 4, '0')
else YourField
end
from YourTable
```